# How to retrieve last four card digits after successfull transaction using Square Point of Sale API?

Tags: square-connect, square

I'm trying to use Square Point Of Sale API in my android app to deal with card payments utilizing square hardware. In order to generate valid customer receipt in my android app, I need to retrieve some information from Square about the card that was used to complete the transaction (such as four last digits).

I've tried to see what data `com.squareup.sdk.pos.ChargeRequest.Success` object returns, but as I understand - it only returns transactions ID's and metadata that was passed from my app to begin with.

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `transactionId` that is returned to you to pass it along to the [BatchRetrieveOrders](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/connect/v2#endpoint-orders-batchretrieveorders) API endpoint (`transaction_id` == `order_id`), in order to find more information about the transaction including the last 4 digits of the card used. The last 4 would be available via `Order->tenders[0]->card_details->card->last_4`.